# Joining an Unavailable column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In a Stored Procedure, When I use the unavailable column in a table to join with an column in temp table then it doesn't throws an error while Compiling. Whereas when I join the same unavailable column with a main table then it throws an error at the time of compilation. May I know the reason for the Cause or behavior.

For Example consider the below query

1. Select TableA.Unknown_Column From TableA   -- This Throws error that "Unknown_Column" does not exists(While Compile)
2. Select TableA.Unknown_Column from TableA  Join #Temp_Table  --This Compiles Successfuly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the temp table exists, the SP will review the code to find inconsistences and throw an error if you refer to some column not present in temp table.
If the temp table does not exist, but you are creating it in your SP, it won't check these inconsistences and it will compile.
More or less... I think this is what's happening to you.

Comment: For Example consider the below query

1. Select TableA.Unknown_Column From TableA   -- This Throws error that "Unknown_Column" does not exists(While Compile)

2. Select TableA.Unknown_Column from TableA  Join #Temp_Table  --This Compiles Successfuly

Comment: @Shahul, can you please edit your question and post your code there? Thanks

Comment: Kindly refer the Updated question. Thanks

Comment: @Shahul please read my answer to figure out why you are receiving/not receiving exception on procedure compile

Answer (score 0):

[temp] table schema is not created on code compile. Or ever before. It created on code execute only. So, SQL Server validates schema on execution.

[Standard] table has already created/known schema, so, when using it in Management or Visual studio, IDE is able to check or your code refers to valid schema (table structure) before compiling object/preventing to compile at this case.